# Django testing doesn't recognize dirty_fields?

Tags: django, django-testing

One of my models uses dirty_fields.  The save method detects when the field `scale_mode` changes.  Once this happens, it goes through all the related `grade` objects and changes the field `score` for each affected `grade`.  The goal is if VSB is swapped with VSBPLUS, then APP is swapped with APP+.

model:

```
class GradeBookSetup(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)

    VSB = 'VSB'
    VSBPLUS = 'VSBPLUS'
    SCALEMODE = [
        ('VSB', 'BEG DEV APP EXT'),
        ('VSBPLUS', 'BEG DEV APP APP+ EXT'),
    ]

    scale_mode = models.CharField(
        max_length=7, choices=SCALEMODE, blank=True, default=VSB)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GradeBookSetup, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.is_dirty():
            dirty_fields = self.get_dirty_fields()
            if 'scale_mode' in dirty_fields:
                if self.scale_mode == "VSB":
                    n = 0
                    objs = Grade.objects.filter(user=self.user)
                    for grade in objs:
                        if grade.score == "APP+":
                            objs[n].score = "APP"
                            n = n + 1
                    Grade.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['score'])
                elif self.scale_mode == "VSBPLUS":
                    objs = Grade.objects.filter(user=self.user)
                    for grade in objs:
                        if grade.score == "APP":
                            objs[n].score = "APP+"
                    Grade.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['score'])

class Grade(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    INCOMPLETE = 'I'
    BEGINNING = 'BEG'
    DEVELOPING = 'DEV'
    APPLYING = 'APP'
    APPLYINGPLUS = 'APP+'
    EXTENDING = 'EXT'

    score = models.CharField(
        max_length=4, blank=True, default=INCOMPLETE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(
        Assessment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    objective = models.ForeignKey(
        Objective, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cblock = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

I am writing tests for this model.  Each of the test below passes except for the last test, `test_scale_mode_change`.

```
class GradeBookSetupTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='tester',
            email='tester@email.com',
            password='tester123'
        )

        cls.gbsetup = GradeBookSetup(
            user=cls.user,
            scale_mode="VSBPLUS",
        )
        cls.gbsetup.save()
        
        cls.student = Student.objects.create(
            user=student_user,
            student_first="Jim",
            student_last="Smith",
            nickname="Jim S",
            fullname="Jim Smith",
            student_number=992342,
            email="992342@learn.vsb.bc.ca"
        )
        cls.course = Course.objects.create(
            user=cls.user,
            course_name="Math8",
            grade_level='ELEM',

        )
        cls.classroom = Classroom(
            user=cls.user,
            classroom_name='Block 1',
            course=cls.course,
        )
        cls.classroom.students.add(cls.student)
        cls.classroom.save()

        cls.objective = Objective.objects.create(
            user=cls.user,
            objective_name='factor.1',
            mode='LA',
            course=cls.course,
            description="Test objective",
        )
        cls.assessment = Assessment(
            user=cls.user,
            assessment_name="Quiz1",
            course=cls.course,
        )
        cls.assessment.objectives.add(cls.objective)
        cls.assessment.save()

        cls.grade = Grade.objects.create(
            user=cls.user,
            score='APP+',
            student=cls.student,
            cblock=cls.classroom,
            assessment=cls.assessment,
            objective=cls.objective
        )

    def test_gradebooksetup_creation(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.gbsetup.scale_mode, "VSBPLUS")
        
    def test_grade_creation(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.grade.score, 'APP+')
        self.assertNotEqual(self.grade.score, 'DEV')

    def test_scale_mode_change(self):
        self.gbsetup.scale_mode = 'VSB'
        self.gbsetup.save()
        print(self.gbsetup.scale_mode)
        self.assertEqual(self.grade.score, 'APP')
```

What I expect to happen is that `self.gbsetup.scale_mode = 'VSB' should trigger the dirty_field in the save method.  This should then change the APP+ score to APP. The print statement confirms that gbsetup == VSB. In practice, my app does perform this function correctly.

What happens though is:

```
self.assertEqual(self.grade.score, 'APP')
AssertionError: 'APP+' != 'APP'
```

I didn't show all the related models for Grade and GradeBookSetup, I don't think they are relevant to this problem. I can add these if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to regrab the grade from the database as the change is made in the DB but the reference instance is still the one created in the setup.

```
def test_scale_mode_change(self):
    self.gbsetup.scale_mode = 'VSB'
    self.gbsetup.save()
    print(self.gbsetup.scale_mode)
    #we have made indirect changes to grade via the gbsetup.save() function that we need to check
    self.grade.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(self.grade.score, 'APP')
```

Comment: SamSparx, you are correct that the `refresh_from_db()` is needed. However, this still does not let the test pass.  I put a print statement following `if self.is_dirty():` and it was never printed to the terminal.  Same with `if 'scale_mode' in dirty_fields:`.

Comment: hmm.  Does that still happen if you place the super.save() call at the end of the save() function?

Comment: That worked.  I need to read up on super.save(), I was not aware of this.  As well, in hindsight I may get rid of the dirty_fields.  Saving a GradeBookSetup should rarely happen (once or twice max per year per user), so there would be minimal overhead in running the `if self.scale_mode == "VSB":` every time a user saves.